# Navigation using Dropbox

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using dropbox as the navigation But it does not go to page selected.
Below I provide code and demo as your reference.

**App Routing Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AComponent } from './a/a.component';
import { BComponent } from './b/b.component';
import { CComponent } from './c/c.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'a', component: AComponent },
  { path: 'b', component: BComponent },
  { path: 'c', component: CComponent },
  { path: 'header', component:HeaderComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**App Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { AComponent } from './a/a.component';
import { BComponent } from './b/b.component';
import { CComponent } from './c/c.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRoutingModule , RouterModule.forRoot([]) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, AComponent, BComponent,  CComponent, HeaderComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

For more reference you can click [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-djxhyk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `router-outlet` tag on you app.component.html so your `app.component.html` should be

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<a routerLink="/b" routerLinkActive="active">b</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<header-app></header-app>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

instead of

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<a routerLink="/b" routerLinkActive="active">b</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<header-app></header-app>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtqmlf)